# Supervisor *** Unknown syntax: reread

Tags: sockets, supervisord

I'm using supervisor to run gunicorn . I'v config supervisored.conf 
and when I'v wanted to execute command :

```
   supervisorctl reread
```

I got this error :

```
   *** Unknown syntax: reread
```

and when I execute command :

```
supervisorctl status
```

I got this error :

```
  error: socket.error, (2, 'No such file or directory'): file: <string> line: 1
```

I got these errors even if I dont config supervisored.conf

Comment: I fix socket .error but still I got   *** Unknown syntax: reread error

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you are not trying to run this command while already running the supervisorctl command, this is what happens for me:

```
$ supervisorctl
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
supervisor> supervisorctl reread
*** Unknown syntax: supervisorctl reread
```